# How to load a page inside drop down menu's container using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a javascript drop down menu from w3schools with slight modification on my part, instead of links I am showing a container. Now I want to show a page inside this container let it be test.php. How to load test.php inside container when droptbtn is clicked.

```js
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.container{
  min-width:300px;
  min-height:400px;
  border:2px solid #666;
  }
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="container"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at Jquerys [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)  function

```
$( "#myDropdown" ).load( "test.php" );
```

So in your click event just use the above to load the right page (`test.php`) into the selector (`#myDropdown`).